# How to create MVVM silverlight application in vs 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, solution-explorer

I am new to the silverlight mvvm pattern. I am searching on the internet to create the mvvm application in silverlight. I found the link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_mvvm_topic2. In this link there are four projects in solution explorer. These are CustomerService.Model, CustomersService, SilverlightCustomerViewer and SilverlightCustomerViewer.Web. I am finding no such article about how to add these projects in solution explorer so that they get available for current project. I dont know how to do that. I created them as follows.
I created the silverlight project in vs 2010 by going to File -> New Project -> Silverlight Application and hosted it in web application project. So I have two projects now in solution explorer.
1. SilverlightCustomerViewer
2. SilverlightCustomerViewer.Web

I dont know how to add the other two projects in the solution explorer through vs 2010 and which template should I use for that ?. Can you please tell me how to do that ? Can ypu please provide me any link or any approach through which I can resolve the above issue. If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CustomerService is the WCF Service Application and CustomerService.Model is the class library of Window Type. You have to add the new project in the solution explorer for both CustomerService and CustomerService.Model projects. You can refer the link http://blogsbynatarajan.blogspot.com/2011/05/silverlight-40-using-mvvm.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the project by right clicking on the solution name and click add project to solution

Comment: which template should I use for CustomersService and CustomerService.Model in vs 2010 ?